# SQL: Finding the count within another table, while retaining records that do not exist in the join

Tags: sql, sql-server

here's one for you guys to really get stuck into. I've spent hours looking at it. I even managed to obtain the count of enrollments, but this of course excluded any records that did not hold an enrollment.

the following query:

```
SELECT 
AccountName, 
EmailAddress, 
DateOfBirth,          
ContactTel,   
RegistrationDate,   
StartDate as LastAudit,   
AccountStatus      

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    acc.AccountName, 
    acc.EmailAddress, 
    u.DateOfBirth, 
    u.LoginID,        
    u.DateCreated as RegistrationDate,
    u.ContactTelephone as ContactTel,
    acs.[Description] as AccountStatus, 
    COUNT(*) over (partition by acc.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth) AS cnt  

    FROM Account AS acc 
    JOIN [User] AS u ON acc.AccountID = u.AccountID      
    JOIN AccountStatus AS acs ON acs.AccountStatusID = acc.AccountStatusID
) ua           
join Audit as aud 
  on aud.LoginID = ua.LoginID 

WHERE cnt > 1
AND EmailAddress IS NOT null
AND DateOfBirth IS NOT null     
AND aud.StartDate = (SELECT MAX(StartDate) as StartDate
                    FROM    Audit as b
                    WHERE b.LoginID = aud.LoginID)   

ORDER BY EmailAddress, DateOfBirth
```

produces results as per below:

```
AccountID  |  AccountName  |  EmailAddress  |    DoB    |  ContactTel  etc etc....
   555           Jo Test          t@t.com     2014/01/02   546489484
   475           Al Test          t@t.com     2014/01/02   84948
   250          Paul Test       my@email.com  2010/05/12   84948
   251          Abby Test       my@email.com  2010/05/12   84948
```

i.e. it finds unqiue Accounts which use the same email and DoB. (duplicates)

Now here's my problem, I have another table which I need to include and I have two options in how to display the data. The table is as follows

EnrolledService Tbl

```
EnrollmentID | ServiceID | AccountID | EnrolledServiceStatusID
   20             2           555              1
   21             3           555              1
   22             1           555              2
   23             1           475              2
```

We can see that an AccountID can have multiple Enrollments. I want to either check if an enrollment exists with a ServiceStatusID of 1, for each account. Or, I want to do a count of how many enrollments an AccountID has with a ServiceStatusID of 1.

We must take into consideration, that an Account may not have ANY enrollments, but I must still records the account as a duplicate.

Are we able to add an EnrollmentCount column in the results, if the Enrollment doesn't exist then the column == 0, or if it does exists, populate the column with the count?

Thanks as always.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2. The EnrolledService table only includes records where an Enrollment exists. So no, not all records are present in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
select AccountID,
      sum(case EnrolledServiceStatusID 
          when 1 then 1
          else 0
          end) as sum_of_EnrolledServiceStatusID 
from the_query1 q1
     left outer join EnrolledService e on q1.AccountID=e.AccountID
group by AccountID
```

You left join the EnrolledService to the first query and add grouping by AccountID. Then count how many EnrolledServiceStatusID met. For each 1 add 1 to the result

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't quite understand. Where should this be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the job, placed in the main select query.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN EnrolledService AS es on es.AccountID = acc.AccountID
GROUP BY AccountName, acc.EmailAddress, DateOfBirth, LoginID, u.DateCreated,      u.ContactTelephone, acs.Description
```